# Problem with non-linear system of PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I wish to solve the following system of hyperbolic PDEs: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\alpha \sqrt{2y-y^2}$, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial v}\:\left(1-y\right)$, for the functions $\alpha=\alpha(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$ on a rectangle aligned with the axes on the first quadrant, and boundary conditions $\alpha (u,0)=1$, $y(u,0)=\sin u+1$, $y(0,v)=1$. However, I posed the problem as follows

```
eq1 = D[y[u, v], u] == \[Alpha][u, v] Sqrt[2 y[u, v] - y[u, v]^2];
eq2 = D[y[u, v], v] \[Alpha][u,v] == -D[\[Alpha][u, v], v] (1 - y[u, v]);
bc = {\[Alpha][u, 0] == 1, y[u, 0] == 1 + Sin[u], y[0, v] == 1};
region = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1.5, 1.5}];
sol = NDSolve[{{eq1, eq2}, bc}, {\[Alpha], y}, {u, v} \[Element]region]
```

but I am not obtaining any solution, just a string of errors starting with

```
NDSolve`FEM`InitializePDECoefficients::femcnsd: The PDE coefficient -(((2-2 y[u,v]) \[Alpha][u,v])/(2 Sqrt[2 y[u,v]-y[u,v]^2])) does not evaluate to a numeric scalar at the coordinate {1.2075,1.2075}; it evaluated to Indeterminate instead.
```

and ending with

```
NDSolve::fempslf: The linearization process in PDESolve failed.
```

Anybody could please guide me about what is going wrong?

Comment: Seems like a blow up of your PDE.

Comment: Please, pay attention that `bc` at `u=0, v=0` are formulated outside of `region`.  Also your `region` is not "a rectangle aligned with the axes on the first quadrant".

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks, I fixed it. The errors however persist.

Comment: Using the FEM is not a good idea for this problem, as it is convection dominated. The tensor product grid method is better in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem can be solve with using option "MethodOfLines". Note, that in a case of boundary condition $\alpha (u,0)=1$ the solution is trivial  $\alpha (u, v)=1$. Nevertheless, `NDSolve` generates solution with some message.

```
eq1 = D[y[u, v], u] == \[Alpha][u, v] Sqrt[2 y[u, v] - y[u, v]^2];
eq2 = D[y[u, v], v] \[Alpha][u, 
     v] == -D[\[Alpha][u, v], v] (1 - y[u, v]);
bc = {\[Alpha][u, 0] == 1, y[u, 0] == 1 + Sin[u], y[0, v] == 1};


sol = NDSolve[{{eq1, eq2}, bc}, {\[Alpha], y}, {u, 0, 1.5}, {v, 0, 
     1.5}, Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic, 
      "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual", 
      "PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MinPoints" -> 41, "MaxPoints" -> 41, 
          "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}}] // Quiet;
```

Visualization

```
{DensityPlot[\[Alpha][u, v] /. sol[[1]], {u, 0, 1.2}, {v, 0, 1.5}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "\[Alpha]", FrameLabel -> {"u", "v"}], 
 DensityPlot[y[u, v] /. sol[[1]], {u, 0, 1.2}, {v, 0, 1.5}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "y", FrameLabel -> {"u", "v"}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]